# Is it possible to encrypt a message stream with the same IV each time and for it to be secure?

Tags: initialization-vector

I know we should ideally never reuse the IV (Depending upon the mode of encryption used), but is it possible to have a protocol which uses the same IV for the message stream and is as safe as one which has a new IV every time?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/forced-into-using-a-static-iv-aes

Comment: Yes, secure to an extent.  Look into misuse resistant encryption such as SIV mode.  This will leak the (in)equality of the plaintext which is really all you can hope for.

Comment: You should ideally also know that [crossposting is not a good ethic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/403350) and you got an answer in Information Security.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Hey Thomas, great to hear from you again! I'd like to add niche modes like Bi-directional Infinite Garble Extensions that would also be secure in the same sense (but without the authentication).